# Why the view does not hide itself even-though the variable is set to false?

Tags: arrays, swiftui

Why `show/hide` button does not hide the each `text` in this code?. I feel like the `@State var meON: Bool = true` have placed in the wrong place or it repeatedly sets the value to `true` no matter if we click the button or not. I tried placing it in other places but does not seems to work. The swiftUI logic is confusing.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct dsfApp: App {
    @StateObject var guideLinesArrayGlobal = GuideLinesArrayObservedMainClass()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(guideLinesArrayGlobal)
        }
    }
}

struct Fruits: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var text: String = ""
    
 }

final class GuideLinesArrayObservedMainClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var guideLinesArray : [Fruits] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var guideLinesArrayLocal: GuideLinesArrayObservedMainClass
    
        
    var body: some View {
        
        Button ("append") {
            guideLinesArrayLocal.guideLinesArray.append (Fruits(id: UUID(), text: "apple" ))
            guideLinesArrayLocal.guideLinesArray.append (Fruits(id: UUID(), text: "orange" ))
            guideLinesArrayLocal.guideLinesArray.append (Fruits(id: UUID(), text: "peach" ))
                                                       
        }
                                                         
       ForEach(guideLinesArrayLocal.guideLinesArray, id: \.id) { fruitss in
           
           
            if let indexForItem = (guideLinesArrayLocal.guideLinesArray.firstIndex {
                $0.id == fruitss.id }) {
                
                @State var IdUnique: UUID = fruitss.id
                @State var meON: Bool = true
                
                HStack {
                    Button ("show/hide"){
                        meON.toggle()
                    }
                    if meON {
                        Text (fruitss.text)}
                }
            }
        }
         
    }
}
```

Comment: `@State` properties are declared outside of the `body` var and not inside it.

Comment: `@State` only works at `struct` level, create a subview if needed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: It's the lowest I can get, it's not possible to put the `@state` properties inside the `HStack` or did you mean something else? If you're saying that they should be placed outside the body, then the whole view would hide/show regardless of the button I press. did you notice that the each fruit have their own button? Each button should only hide/show their assigned fruit.

Comment: I don’t care about the functionality or the design of your code, `@State` properties are declared outside of the `body`. That is how SwiftUI works.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks got it working after making it a seperate different struct and view and @binding. I wonder why swiftui allowed me to use `@State` after the `for each` if it already knows that it will not run the `@state` if it's not in the `struct` level. No errors at all.

Comment: I agree that it's strange you don't get an error.